# generate 2 rows for each row in spark using optimized DSL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, explode, flatmap

I have data like:

```
id,ts_start,ts_end,foo_start,foo_end
1,1,2,f_s,f_e
2,3,4,foo,bar
3,3,6,foo,f_e
```

I.e. a single record with all the start and end information aggregated.
Using a flat map, these could be transformed to

```
id,ts,foo
1,1,f_s
1,2,f_e
```

How can I do the same using the optimized SQL DSL with `explode` or maybe `pivot`?

### edit

Obviously, I do not want to read in the data two times and union the result.

Or is this the only option if I do not want to use flatmap + serde + custom code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

given:

```
val df = Seq(
  (1,1,2,"f_s","f_e"),
  (2,3,4,"foo","bar"),
  (3,3,6,"foo","f_e")
).toDF("id","ts_start","ts_end","foo_start","foo_end")
```

you can do:

```
df
  .select($"id",
    explode(
      array(
       struct($"ts_start".as("ts"),$"foo_start".as("foo")),
       struct($"ts_end".as("ts"),$"foo_end".as("foo"))
     )
    ).as("tmp")
  )
  .select(
    $"id",
    $"tmp.*"
  )
  .show()
```

which gives:

```
+---+---+---+
| id| ts|foo|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  1|f_s|
|  1|  2|f_e|
|  2|  3|foo|
|  2|  4|bar|
|  3|  3|foo|
|  3|  6|f_e|
+---+---+---+
```